# How to select and AMI when creating an instance of EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I am using Amazon EC2 for the first time, and need to create an instance that runs **Windows, MSSQL Server 2008, .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and IIS Server 6.0.** I am unable to decide what AMI (out of the huge list of community AMIs) should I choose to meet my requirements. Is there a way I can make this decision without doing trial and error.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look through the [list of available Windows AMIs](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/kbcategory.jspa?categoryID=209) on the AWS web site; if you sort by title you should be able to spot suitable candidates fairly quickly.

You may be out of luck with the particular combination of versions you're looking for, since most installations of MSSQL Server 2008 are likely to be on Windows Server 2008, which usually has IIS 7.0 installed rather than 6.0.